# Redirect some page to http and some page to https

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have used this code for redirecting to https:

```
RewriteEngine on
#Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.mysite.com/test/$1 [R,L]
```

but I need some pages using http not to https.

Example:
I need this url: `http://www.mysite.com/test/contact.php`

Comment: you need http for contact.php only..?

Comment: this is for example I need two or three page without https

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
#Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.mysite.com/test/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} \/contact\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(contact.php)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Its redirect all the pages to http

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in PHP as well with some conditional statements and header something like

```
if(something) {
   header("Location: https://www.example.com/");
}
```

Be sure not to output anything before header()

Answer (score 0):

That is the condition

```
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !\/contact\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/test/$1 [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} \/contact\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/test/$1 [R,L]
```